# The System.InvalidOperationException when use ml.net predictionEnginePool

Tags: ml.net

when I execute the `_predictionEnginePool.Predict(modelName: "**", example: input)`
throw an exception:
Can't bind the IDataView column 'label' of type 'Key<UInt32, 0-1>' to field or property 'Label' of type 'System.String'

What's the the reason?

Comment: Was you able to resolve the issue somehow?